# Same Presenter working with different Repositories

Tags: design-patterns

You do you manage the same presenter working with different repositories using the MVP pattern?

I just have multiple constructor overloads and the presenter simply uses the one that is suitable for the scenario.

```
AddCustomerPresenter presenter = new AddCustomerPresenter(this,customerRepository); 
presenter.AddCustomer(); 

presenter = new AddCustomerPresenter(this,archiveRepository); 
presenter.Archive();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Will!

But CustomerRepository and ArchiveRepository are not related in any way. They are two completely different things.

Answer (score 1):

Why not have

```
IRepository { /* .. */ }
CustomerRepository : IRepository { /* .. */ }
ArchiveRepository : IRepository { /* .. */ }
```

and then

```
AddCustomerPresenter {
IRepository Store {get;set;}
public AddCustomerPresenter(IRepository store) { /*...*/ }
/*...*/
}
```

Your presenter should NOT have any static dependency on ANY implementation of IRepository.  If you find there's no other way, you need to rework your design because it's probably flawed.